# how to locate source code path from module

Tags: python, setup.py, site-packages

I have a python package built from source code in `/Document/pythonpackage` directory

```
/Document/pythonpackage/> python setup.py install
```

This creates a folder in `site-packages` directory of python

```
import pythonpackage
print(pythonpackage.__file__)
>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonpackage-x86_64.egg/pythonpackage/__init__.py
```

I am running a script on multiple environments so the only path I know I will have is `pythonpackage.__file__`. However Document/pythonpackage has some data that is not in site-packages is there a way to automatically find the path to `/Document/pythonpackage` given that you only have access to the module in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working like that is discouraged.  it's generally assumed that after installing a package the user can remove the installation directory (as most automated package managers would do).  instead you'd make sure your `setup.py` copied any data files over into the relevant places, and then your code would pick them up from there.

assuming you're using the standard `setuptools`, you can see the docs on [Including Data Files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files), which says at the bottom:

> In summary, the three options allow you to:
>
> `include_package_data`
>
> Accept all data files and directories matched by MANIFEST.in.
>
> `package_data`
>
> Specify additional patterns to match files that may or may not be matched by MANIFEST.in or found in source control.
>
> `exclude_package_data`
>
> Specify patterns for data files and directories that should not be included when a package is installed, even if they would otherwise have been included due to the use of the preceding options.

and then says:

> Typically, existing programs manipulate a package’s `__file__` attribute in order to find the location of data files. However, this manipulation isn’t compatible with PEP 302-based import hooks, including importing from zip files and Python Eggs. It is strongly recommended that, if you are using data files, you should use the ResourceManager API of `pkg_resources` to access them

Comment: Thank you for the informative response. The package_data flags was something I wanted to know for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you could create a repository for your module and use pip to install it. The egg folder would then have a file called PKG-INFO which would contain the url to the repository you imported your module from.